# Hydraulic System simulation

Tags: c++, memory, simulation, abstract, directed-acyclic-graphs

I got this problem to solve : I have an Hydraulic System whose components are sources, sinks, taps, simple tubes, T tubes and X tubes who perform some actions on the water flux (sources generate the flux, T tubes split it in half in the two branches of the HSystem, X tubes split the flux deriving from two branches in 1/3 and 2/3, sink collect the flux and so on). Clearly, I can have more than one source and more than one sink. The user sets the input flux for each source (an integer number) and I have to provide the amount of water collected in each sink.

Therefore, I created a base class "Component" where I stored the component name, the flux it passes to the next component, some getter and a virtual method to simulate its behavior. Then I derived the other classes for the other components implementing the virtual method. Eventually I created the HydraulicSystem class where I stored in a vector of Component all my components, but since "Component" is an abstract class I can't instanciate objects therefore I can only store pointers of type Component.
What I thought eventually is that each component can take trace of what other component comes before  (2  for X tubes, 1 otherwise) and simulate the HSystem going backwards from sinks like this (I'm gonna write some implementation next to definition just to make it easier to read)

```cpp
class Component{
public:
//constructor and destructor
//...
//
vector<Component*> getConnected() const;
int simulate() = 0;
private:
string _name;
int flux;
vector<Component*> _connected;

}

class T_Tube : public Component{
public:
//...

 int simulate() { 
for(int i=0;i<_connected.size();i++){
flux = ...
private :
...
}
 return flux;
}

class Sink : public Component{
public :
...
int simulate(){
return getConnected()[0]->simulate();
}
private :
...
}

// other classes
}
```

then in the HSystem class starting from each sink I call its simulate method which calls the simulate from the component connect to him and so on. This approach seemed to work, but since I need to use "new" to add new components to my HSystem, somewhere I also need to free this memory but if I try to do this in HSystem destructor I got troubles because Component itself has a vector of type Component. I tried also using intelligent pointers but it didn't work either.
What I can't get is why my program works fine and I don't get memory leaks or segmentation faults if I don't care of freeing memory?

Do you think it might be a better idea if I give up on the original idea to maintain locally in each component the piece of information of who comes before and I organize the all HSystem like a DAG ? In this case, I though to make a topological sort of the graph, but how can I simulate it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is far too much contextual information here and the core of the question is lost. Maybe removing some of the unnecessary information and breaking it up into paragraphs will help. I was not able to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

The general way is to hold `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>`.  References to other `Component`s should either be a raw pointer (if you can be sure the `Component` will still exist), or `std::weak_ptr` (if not).

However, for this application there is no point managing memory like this.  The logic is:

1. Read user input and create all components
2. Simulate system
3. Free memory ?
4. Exit

Step 3 is pointless, because step 4 will do it anyway.  So just store raw pointers and don't bother with `delete`.

Note that this approach doesn't work if you loop round simulating multiple systems in the same program run (you can exhaust memory), but actually running a new process is probably the right way to handle that.

Comment: _"So just store raw pointers and don't bother with `delete`."_ That's bad design though, and makes it harder to refactor the code in future maintenance. Using smart pointers is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about the last part? Do you think  a different approach like a DAG might work better?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not worrying about unnecessary complexity (and in this context memory management *is* unnecessary complexity) is *good* design in my book.  Also YAGNI - adding smart pointers later won't be a huge change.  Finally this is (clearly) an educational assignment, so the OP **really** ain't gonna need it.

Comment: @Elle I don't know.  I don't really think that "what's a good design for this problem" is a good question for Stack Overflow - sorry.